# Angular6 innerHtml not binding routerLink

Tags: angular, angular-routing

```
this.dataAccessList ="<li routerLinkActive=" + "\"active selected\"" + ">" + "<a href='#' class='has-arrow' aria-expanded='false'>" +"<span class='has-icon'>" + "<i class='icon-laptop_windows'></i></span>" +       "<span class='nav-title'>Control</span></a>" +"<ul aria-expanded='true' class='collapse in'>"+"<li>" +"<a href='#' [routerLink]="+"\"['/dashboard']\""+">General</a>" +"</li>" +"</ul></li>";
```

I created  the above `routerLink` in dynamically.

next I call the `app.component.html`

```
<div [innerHTML]="dataAccessList"></div>
```

but `routerLink` is not working.

Comment: can you provide code what you have done so far.

Comment: yup stackblitz will help

Comment: app.component.ts  code                                                                            this.dataAccessList ="<li routerLinkActive=" + "\"active selected\"" + ">" + "<a href='#' [routerLink]="+"\"['/dashboard']\""+">General</a>" +"</li>" ;                                                                                                                                                                 app.component.html code                                                                                           <div [innerHTML]="dataAccessList"></div> . Not Working in routerLink

Comment: Did you import RouterModule into app.module??

Comment: yes , i imported routermodule

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the `CommonModule` in you app.module.ts